# h1 background color wired behavior with box shadow

Tags: html, css, sass, tailwind-css, framer-motion

i'm using framer-motion and tailwind css:

when i add a boxShadow to my h1 i get this wired behavior :

[image example of what the bug produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU7l3.png)

this is my code :

```
<motion.div
        className=" relative  text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight text-default-800 sm:text-6xl text-center bg-transparent z-0"

      >
<motion.h1
          className="text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight text-default-800 sm:text-6xl text-center shadow-2xl shadow-secondary-500  block w-fit  mx-auto relative z-10 "
          initial={{ scale: 0.85, y: 30, opacity: 0 }}
          whileInView={{
            scale: 1,
            y: 0,
            opacity: 1,
            transition: {
              duration: 1,
              ease: "backInOut",
              bounce: 1.5,
              delay: 0.7,
            },
          }}
          viewport={{ once: true }}
        >
          prices choose ur best plan
        </motion.h1>
</motion.div>
```

thanks in advance for your time

i set the h1 background to transparent but it didn't change anything